# How is this element being hidden? How to Capture it

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for ways on how this HTML element is being hidden.

The HTML DOM on load looks like this for an example,

```
<div class=""> 
   <header>
       <!---->
       <!---->
       <!---->
   </header>
</div>
```

After initiating a click event, the HTML DOM changes to this;

```
<div class="container"> 
   <header>
       <!---->
       <div class="show"></div>
       <!---->
   </header>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how its doing this? Also, is there a way to capture this live element? I have a click event elsewhere in the DOM that triggers the **show** element, I have also tried the **on** function but it shows as undefined. Bear in mind, this is not my own site.

I hope this makes sense, thanks let me know If I need to edit or suggest any changes

Answer (score 0):

it's something similar to this, where `class="show"` or `hide` are css classes that set the element to `display:none` or `block`

this example is meant for demonstration only

```js
div=document.querySelectorAll("div")
btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
   i=Math.floor(Math.random()*div.length)
   console.log(div[i])
    div[i].setAttribute("class","show")
})
```

```css
.hide{display:none};
.show{display:block};
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
   <header id="h">
      <div class="hide">a</div>
       <div class="hide">v</div>
       <div class="hide">x</div>
   </header>
</div>

<button id="btn">show</button>
```